# xpath indexing not working in karate UI Framework

Tags: karate

I have 4 tables on my web page, and I need to identify the header for all tables. Now issue is they all have same DOM structure so for identifying them I need to use indexing with xpath like:

`(//span[@data-testid='headcol-0']/div/div[1])[2]`
here last [2] is index for second table identification. So when I have used this xpath it is failing and not identifying the locator correctly.
Do we have any other syntax for indexing here in @karate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `locateAll()` and then an index. Note that this may not work in 0.9.5, please try 0.9.6.RC4

```
* def temp = locateAll("//span[@data-testid='headcol-0']/div/div[1]")[1]
```

Also prefer CSS locators like this:

```
* locate('table:nth-child(3)').highlight()
```

Also new in 0.9.6.RC4 - if you can easily find a child in that table, you can use `element.parent` to navigate "upwards":

```
* def temp = locate('.my-class').parent.parent
```