# Error with xpath indexing in UI Karate Framework v(1.0.1)

Tags: karate

I have a table with complex structure and one cell in row may contains a few elements

> - def locator = "(//div[contains(@class,'someClass')]//div[contains(@class,'someClass')])[1]//div[contains(@class,'someClass')]/div"

And when try to handle it with:

> locateAll(loc)[0].getLocator()

I catch an error: Is not a valid selector

Also: I found a question that was created a year and a half ago and the solution proposed there does not fit to me
[xpath indexing not working in karate UI Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63464982/xpath-indexing-not-working-in-karate-ui-framework)

Also: Karate as far as I understand it does not allow building chains. For example something like this locateAll(rootLocator)[0].locate(prefixLocator)

Comment: I have no suggestions other than point you to this answer. and please note that karate is open-source and you are welcome to contribute code to improve it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65590055/143475